# how can replace using gsub?

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a data like below, I would like to replace `colnames`.

```
da

    ..B1  ..B2 ..B3
a      1     2    1
b      1     1    1
```

Preferred Output:

```
      B1    B2   B3
a      1     2    1
b      1     1    1
```

and I used this command but it did not work:

```
da=gsub(pattern = "..", replacement = "", x = colnames(da))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` is a metacharacter denoting to any character.  So, if we use

```
 gsub("..", "", x= colnames(da))
```

the result will be

```
#[1] "" "" ""
```

as all the characters are removed.  We need to either use `fixed = TRUE` or escape the `.`

```
colnames(da) <- gsub("..", "", x= colnames(da), fixed=TRUE)
colnames(da)
#[1] "B1" "B2" "B3"

gsub("\\.+", "", colnames(da))
#[1] "B1" "B2" "B3"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your last command works good. But can I have changed colnames with row names and value, like Output?

Comment: @tob  If you want to change the column names with rownames, `colnames(da) <- rownames(da)`

Comment: @akrun Please close the brackets gsub("..", "", x= colnames(da)

Comment: @Arunkumarmahesh  Thank you, Good observation!

Answer (score 1):

The following would work as well:

```
da<-data.frame(..B1=c(1,1), ..B2=c(2,1), ..B3=c(1,1))

colnames(da) <- gsub("[.]","", x=colnames(da))
```

With the side note that this would remove any period that is at any position in the name; in some situations you do not want that. The following would remove two periods that are at the start:

```
colnames(da) <- gsub("^..","", x=colnames(da))
```

Answer (score 1):

Function [[:punct:]] is used to remove punctuation character**: ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | }**

```
colnames(da) <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","",colnames(da))
> da
      B1 B2 B3
    1  1  2  1
    2  1  1  1
```